# Trying to create list with ECT

Tags: list, powershell, external-content-type

I'm trying to create list from External content types with powershell. I'm trying to get the model, through this line : 
    $Model = Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogMetadataObject -BdcObjectType Model -Name $ModelName -ServiceContext $ServiceContext

But $Model is null. I'm not sure about what to put in ServiceContext is it the Url of my central administration ? Or of my site ? And also for the noun of my Model, I went in the central administration, in the BDC and used the entire name which is : PPMO.Model.Portefeuille_SAP.

Do i have to use this one ?

Any advice would help, 
Thanks by advance :).

Thoma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This contains an excellent example of what to do, enjoy!

http://blog.netnerds.net/2011/09/sharepoint-powershell-batch-import-models-create-ects-set-permissions/

(this should set the model name for you, I believe the ServiceContext should refer to your CA e.g. your localhost, as this is where the BDCM will be imported)